# Cannot find a suitable constructor for ServiceHost

Tags: c#, wcf

When initializing `ServiceHost`, I can find only two constructors in my VS 2012: `ServiceHost(Object, Uri[])` and `ServiceHost(Type, Uri[])`. But I need a constructor without `Uri[]` as I would config address/binding/contract in `app.config`.

I saw a demo in Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform(Fifth Edition)

```
using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(XXX)))
{

    serviceHost.Open();
    ......
}
```

But I cannot use this constructor,as [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost(v=vs.110).aspx) provides only two constructors:

```
ServiceHost(Object, Uri[])
ServiceHost(Type, Uri[])
```

I think it's better to configure the address in `app.config` instead of in `Uri[]` in constructor

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add an actual question to your post as it's not quite clear what are you asking about. Like "how do I [do that]?" What do you mean by "I can find only two constructors"? If you try the third one as it is described in msdn, does it work? Or does an error occur? Best regards.

Comment: ths for your advice @YakovL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter is (essentially) optional.  If you look at the documentation, you'll note the following signature:

```
public ServiceHost(Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
```

Note the `params` keyword in front of the `Uri[] baseAddresses` parameter.  The [`params`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) allows you to send a comma-delimited list or an array of parameters of the specified type, or no arguments at all.

So `ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(XXX))` is simply calling the `ServiceHost(Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)` constructor with no arguments for the `baseAddresses` parameter.